# How to add a nested list with gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Can someone help me please with implementation of a nested list via gspread?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUunB.png) of what i want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to create a dropdown list in a cell.

  - From your following sample image and "a nested list" in your question, I understood like this.

    - [image]
- You want to achieve this using gspread of python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, I think that it is required to use the batchUpdate method.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, please use your script for retrieving `credentials` of `client = gspread.authorize(credentials)`. And please set the variables. When you run this script, the dropdown list is created in the cell "A1" of "Sheet1" in `spreadsheetId`. The dropdownlilst is from your sample image.

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet ID.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName).id
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "dataValidation": {
                                    "condition": {
                                        "values": [
                                            {
                                                "userEnteredValue": "help"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "userEnteredValue": "me"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "userEnteredValue": "please"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "type": "ONE_OF_LIST"
                                    },
                                    "showCustomUi": True
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "dataValidation"
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: @andreykirv Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @andreykirv @Tanaike I am trying to apply the same above code to entire H column which is the 8th column by giving `"startColumnIndex": 7, "endColumnIndex": 9` but only H1 cell is getting updated. any idea where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @Mahesh About your question of `I am trying to apply the same above code to entire H column which is the 8th column by giving "startColumnIndex": 7, "endColumnIndex": 9 but only H1 cell is getting updated. any idea where I am doing it wrong?`, I would like to support you. But this question is not your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a drop down list that you can edit manually, you can do it with no code. Here are the steps:

#1 Select the cell you want the list to be, then go to Data > Data Validation:

[image: Showing where data validation is]

#2 Select "List of Items" under criteria:

[image: Show criteria selection]

#3 Then type in your values, separated by a comma:

[image]

#4 Press save, and click the carrot to see your drop down list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a convenient way to the same and found https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting.

Here is the part where Data Validation rules are described:
https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting#getting-and-setting-data-validation-rules-for-cells-and-cell-ranges

To install run `pip install gspread-formatting`.
Hope that helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32377742)