# Add dropdown menu (nested list) to Google Spreadsheat with gspread / Google Spread API to whole column

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am struggling to insert a dropdown menu into a Google Spreadsheet using the gspread module in python.

This question explains how to get a dropdown menu in a spreadsheet:

[How to add a nested list with gspread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388351/how-to-add-a-nested-list-with-gspread/66396005#66396005)

However, even if I change the startColumnIndex and endColumnIndex the dropdown menu only shows up in one cell.

I have experimented with something like this:

```
data = sheet.get_all_values()
values = [request if e[3] != "" else "" for e in data]
cells = sheet.range("C1:C%d" % len(values))
for i, e in enumerate(cells):
    e.value = values[i]
sheet.update_cells(cells)
```

where request is the dropdown menu. So I want to insert a dropdown menu in the fourth column if the third column is not empty, else I don't want to insert anything.
But as of now, this only works if request is a regular string and not the dropdown formatted cell I want it to be.

[This picture shows what I want. You can see that row 1, 3, and 4 have a dropdown list in the fourth column (as the third column is not empy) while row 2 doesn't have anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfe2l.png)

It seems to be that it would be batch to use the batch_update module in combination with request and not the loop but I don't seem to get it working for multiple cells at the same time (preferably a whole column).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `where request is the dropdown menu. So I want to insert a dropdown menu in the fourth column if the third column is not empty, else I don't want to insert anything.`. Can you provide your expected goal as an image?

Comment: No problem! I added a picture to the initial question that hopefully makes it a bit more clear as to what I am trying to do :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for the offer and it is all good! So let me rephrase it: I have a spreadsheet with three columns of data (so A, B, and C). I only want to add a dropdown menu if the last column (C) in the row is not empty.

I figured out how to check whether the column is empty, and I figured out how I can add a drop down menu. However, I can only add one dropdown menu for some reason and it doesn't want to add a whole column of those. 

Is this more clear?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When column "C" is not empty, you want to insert a dropdown list to column "D".
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
# Please use your gspread client.

spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set sheet name.
dropdownOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # This is from your showing image.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
sheetId = sheet.id
v = [{"userEnteredValue": str(e)} for e in dropdownOptions]
values = sheet.get_all_values()[1:]
requests = [
    {
        "setDataValidation": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": sheetId,
                "startRowIndex": i + 1,
                "endRowIndex": i + 2,
                "startColumnIndex": 3,
                "endColumnIndex": 4,
            },
            "rule": {
                "showCustomUi": True,
                "strict": True,
                "condition": {"values": v, "type": "ONE_OF_LIST"},
            },
        }
    }
    for i, r in enumerate(values)
    if r[2] != ""
]
spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- When this script is run, all values are retrieved and searched in column "C". When column "C" is empty, a dropdown list is inserted into column "D".

#### Note:

- From your showing image, it supposes that your Spreadsheet has the 1st header row. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [SetDataValidationRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setdatavalidationrequest)

Comment: The problem with this is that for some reason the whole spreadsheet gets filled with dropdown menu's. So not only in column D but every cell that is filled (or not filled) with data.

Comment: @user20300605 Thank you for replying. About `The problem with this is that for some reason the whole spreadsheet gets filled with dropdown menu's. So not only in column D but every cell that is filled (or not filled) with data. `, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my script, the dropdown list is inserted to the column "D" that the column "C" is no empty. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @user20300605 For example, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue of `The problem with this is that for some reason the whole spreadsheet gets filled with dropdown menu's. So not only in column D but every cell that is filled (or not filled) with data.`? By the way, I tested the Spreadsheet of your provided image. I apologize for this.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong, but I reimplemented your code and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than 500 items you will need to define a range instead of a list of values. Here's a utility function you can use to accomplish that. Peep the use of the utility function `a1_range_to_grid_range` to make life easy when creating the range dictionary the API requires:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='key.json')
workbook = gc.open_by_key(current_global_sheet_id)

def create_dropdown(workbook, placement_sheet_name, range_sheet_name, sheet_range, placement_cell):
        '''
        workbook: gspread workbook object
        placement_sheet_name: sheet name where dropdown will be placed
        range_sheet_name: sheet name where dropdown values are located
        sheet_range: range of dropdown values
        placement_cell: cell where dropdown will be placed
        '''
    
        grid_range = gspread.utils.a1_range_to_grid_range(placement_cell)
        ## create dropdown with SKUS
        worksheet = workbook.worksheet(placement_sheet_name)
        sheetId = worksheet.id
        grid_range['sheetId'] = sheetId
        reqs = [
            {
                "setDataValidation": {
                    "range": grid_range,
                    "rule": {
                        "showCustomUi": True,
                        "strict": True,
                        "condition": {"values": [{"userEnteredValue": f"='{range_sheet_name}'!{sheet_range}"}], "type": "ONE_OF_RANGE"},
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
        workbook.batch_update({"requests": reqs}) 

create_dropdown(workbook, 'Charts', 'Data', 'B1:B', 'B3')
```

a dropdown like this is created:
[image: gsheet_dropdown]